# finding pageradapter page index w/ more than one page on screen android

Tags: java, android, indexing, android-viewpager

I'm adding pages at run time to a PagerAdapter. I have 2 pages on screen at a time. When I call getCurrentItem, it returns the page index of the page on the left of the screen. If I click on an item on the page on the right, I am wanting to get that page's index, not the page on the left.

Any idea's of how to go about this?

this is pagerAdapter w/o fragments

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: Im sorry I can't at this time. getCurrentItem() is the idea of what I'm looking for, but since I have 2 pages on screen, I find that getCurrentItem() always returns the index of the left hand page. Im calling getCurrentItem() from within setOnClickListener within an ArrayAdapter. each page of the PagerAdapter is a ListView with the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Maybe having a separate click event for the PagerAdapter it's self is the way to do this

Comment: What about referencing the containing page from the ArrayAdapter? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I put this code to find the PagerAdapter index of the clicked page. This code was used in the setOnClickListener in the getView() of the ArrayAdapter class...

```
viewPager.getAdapter().getItemPosition(v.getParent().getParent())
```